# API adds default value to optionnal parameter

Tags: python, metabase

I am discovering the Metabase API And trying to work with it, here posting cards (questions) to my database.
I have been able to successfully push cards which worked well, but I have encountered a problem when working with parameters.

Here is the query I wish to put on:

```sql
select
    id,
    duration_s
from
    logs.sessions
where
    duration_s > {{min_duration}}
    [[and duration_s < {{max_duration}}]]
```

Where both my parameters are numbers

- min_duration is required and has a default value of 60
- max_duration is **not** required and has no default value

I have a dict as such:

```py
    params ={
        "visualization_settings": {},
        "can_write": True,
        "description": "A card generated by the API",
        "collection_position": None,
        "result_metadata": None,
        "collection_id": 14,
        "name": "API-generated_question_23",
        "dataset_query": {
            "database": 2,
            "native": {
                "query": "select\n\tid,\n\tduration_s\nfrom\n\tlogs.sessions\nwhere\n\tduration_s > {{min_duration}}\n\t[[and duration_s < {{max_duration}}]]",
                "template-tags": {
                    "max_duration": {
                        "display-name": "Maximum",
                        "name": "max_duration",
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "min_duration": {
                        "default": 69,
                        "display-name": "Minimum",
                        "name": "min_duration",
                        "type": "number",
                        "required": True
                    }
                }
            },
            "type": "native"
        },
        "display": "table"
    }
```

and my request such as

```py
    response = requests.post(url+'/card',
                        headers=header,
                        json=params)
```

It does work and returns me the newly created card

```json
{
    "description": "A card generated by the API",
    "archived": false,
    "collection_position": null,
    "table_id": null,
    "result_metadata": [],
    "creator": {
        "email": "me@mycompanyemail.com",
        "first_name": "Me",
        "last_login": "2023-02-23T10:26:34.275159Z",
        "is_qbnewb": false,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "id": 9,
        "last_name": "Lastname",
        "date_joined": "2023-01-16T15:45:20.278266Z",
        "common_name": "Me Lastname"
    },
    "can_write": true,
    "database_id": 2,
    "enable_embedding": false,
    "collection_id": 14,
    "query_type": "native",
    "name": "API-generated_question_23",
    "dashboard_count": 0,
    "creator_id": 9,
    "updated_at": "2023-02-23T10:26:34.380234Z",
    "made_public_by_id": null,
    "embedding_params": null,
    "cache_ttl": null,
    "dataset_query": {
        "database": 2,
        "native": {
            "query": "select\n\tid,\n\tduration_s\nfrom\n\tlogs.sessions\nwhere\n\tduration_s > {{min_duration}}\n\t[[and duration_s < {{max_duration}}]]",
            "template-tags": {
                "max_duration": {
                    "display-name": "Maximum",
                    "name": "max_duration",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "min_duration": {
                    "default": 69,
                    "display-name": "Minimum",
                    "name": "min_duration",
                    "type": "number",
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "native"
    },
    "id": 58,
    "display": "table",
    "visualization_settings": {},
    "collection": {
        "description": null,
        "archived": false,
        "slug": "empty_collection",
        "color": "#509EE3",
        "name": "empty collection",
        "personal_owner_id": null,
        "id": 14,
        "location": "/11/12/",
        "namespace": null
    },
    "created_at": "2023-02-23T10:26:34.380234Z",
    "public_uuid": null
}
```

All of this is correct, but I have a few problems:
First, when I go on my card, there are two identical default parameters
[image: the default value problem]

The url is `https://metabase.my_company.com/question/58?max_duration=69&min_duration=69` for no reason rather than just `https://metabase.my_company.com/question/58`
Which obviously doesn't work because it must be used to set an interval so this makes the requests looks bugged. I have not asked it to use the default parameter of the second parameter to fill the first one.

Then I have an other problem which is more abstract, it is that there are a lot of parameters I do not understand because they are not explained.
The [documentation about cards](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/api/card#post-apicard) is... existing, and it does specify the types of parameters, but not what they should be in case of dicts and they do not say what they represent! The only way to make this work was to read the requests sent by Metabase when creating a card through the interface with the Network developper tool.

Any hint, pointers or better documentation would be appreciated. This seems very opaque because compared to the JSON Package sent through the website, I was not able to spot what would be the difference between my use of the API and the website.

Thank you very much for reading. <3

P.S.: There might be errors in the SQL request in itself or whatsoever. Please do not mind, I edited it to avoid showing data but I may have left typos in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It is needed to specify an id for each parameters

```json
                "template-tags": {
                    "max_duration": {
                        "display-name": "Maximum",
                        "name": "max_duration",
                        "type": "number",
                        "required": False,
                        "default": None,
                        "id": "alpha"
                    },
                    "min_duration": {
                        "display-name": "Minimum",
                        "name": "min_duration",
                        "type": "number",
                        "required": True,
                        "default": 59,
                        "id": "beta"
                    }
                }
```

adding an id did the trick